# Why does my AST generator trigger syntax error for a notebook file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, abstract-syntax-tree

I tried to generate an AST of a notebook. Some files are okay to generate that, but I sometimes I got this syntax error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/jupyterss/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_1646908/2768568584.py", line 4, in <cell line: 4>
    my_asts = extract_my_asts(notebook_path)

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_1646908/887352820.py", line 21, in extract_my_asts
    parsed_code = ast.parse(cell.source)

  File "/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 50, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,

  File "<unknown>", line 21
    %matplotlib inline
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is the notebook I tried to generate the AST:
https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/03_classification.ipynb

Comment: `%matplotlib inline` simply isn't valid Python syntax.

Comment: Notebooks accept a lot of not-Python syntax.

Comment: I know, but how can I get the ast of the notebook which has the notebook magic function?